# GmailApp requires the script to run as user and SpreadsheetApp requires authorization of the owner?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have written a google apps script that captures information from my employees, and writes this in a spreadsheet which only I can access.It also mails the employee, what information they have filled.The script is embedded in my google site.
The **problem** is,I have to run the script as the owner to be able to edit the spreadsheet and to send the email the script has to be run as the 'user running the script'.

Answer (score 0):

Probable solution is the above problem is to set the script's trigger `onChnage` i.e. on Change of the spreadsheet on any record / any row the Email relevant that email address on that row mail will be send.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Given your scenario, you want your script to run in both modes - 'User executing the app' and as yourself which is clearly not possible. However, there are some workarounds you can use.

1. Set the script to run as the user accessing the app and change the permission of your spreadsheet to provide access to 'Anyone with the link'. That way, no other employee can access or discover the spreadsheet other than if they somehow know the spreadsheet id.
2. The other option is to set the scrip to run as yourself, keep the spreadsheet private and exploit the replyTo and name options of advanced arguments ( https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_mailapp#sendEmail ). To the recipient, the email will 'appear' to have come from someone else. 
   Note, using option 2, you'll run into [Issue 2004](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2004)